# Blow up of indeterminacy locus of rational map -- behaviour on subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X-->Y$ be a (dominant) rational map between irreducible projective varieties with indeterminacy locus $C\subset X$. There is a unique blow up $g:Z\to X$ defined by the behaviour of $f$ at $C$ such that there is a regular morphism $h:Z\to Y$ with $h=g\circ f$.

Now let $A$ be a proper irreducible subvariety of $X$ containing $C$ as proper subset and denote $B$ the image of $A$ under $f$. Likewise the rational map $f_A:A-->B$ admits a blow up $g_A:Z_A\to A$ and a map $h_A:Z_A\to B$ with $h_A=g_A\circ f_A$. The set $Z_A$ can be regarded as a subvariety of $Z$ and $h_A$ the restriction of $h$ to $Z_A$.

It is easy to see that $Z_A$ is an irreducible component of $h^{-1}(B)$. But...

Under which conditions is $Z_A=h^{-1}(B)$ ?

Thanks in advance for any hint.